# ASP.NET Membership.. Handle large amounts of users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a membership contains more than 30,000 user. I'm trying to let a user find or search in all the membership users with their profiles, I'm going to achieve this by importing all users with the needed profiles data into a DataTable and start selecting from it, BUT the problem here that it takes ages to load more than 30,000 user and get their profiles data into a DataTable
Is there any kind of storage that i can pre-load the Membership Users inside, instead of loading it while user is trying to search.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading all 30.000 into memory you could just execute the search query against your database. That will return less rows and have a greater performance. The Membership class has a [FindUsersByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa5st8b2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method that can return paged data.

If you really want to store all the users into memory have a look at [HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx). If you load all your users into the cache, you can then query them with Linq To Objects and get a good performance.

You can fill the cache in the [Application Autostart](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) event. The cache data will then always be loaded when the application is running. You can use a [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) to make sure that your cache is always correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. selecting from database wont work for me due to difference in data storage types.
the second scenario is great but how to achieve it on remote server (my server is GoDaddy)

Comment: Those are all things you can do from code. As long as your project is not running on a webfarm your cache can be in memory. If not, you can put the cache in it's own database. ASP.NET will manage it for you and it's pretty fast (or move your hosting to Azure and use their Caching http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356.aspx)